# Adding a percentage (%) sign to each value while using select sql statement

Tags: mysql

I run the below select query

"*Select Name as Name, Score1 as Sem1, Score2 as Sem2, Score3 as Sem3 from table*"

Here Score1, Score2, Score3 has numerical values in it. Currently the data what i get is as follows

```
Name    Sem1    Sem2    Sem3
Rohit   75      68      92
Rahul   85      79      66
Joy     80      45      81
```

I need the query to throw the following output.

```
Name    Sem1    Sem2    Sem3
Rohit   75%     68%     92%
Rahul   85%     79%     66%
Joy     80%     45%     81%
```

Request you to provide me a solution for this.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is: concat a `%` string to the specified fields.

So,

Use MySQL [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function.

```
"Select Name as Name, CONCAT(Score1, '%') as Sem1, CONCAT(Score2, '%') as Sem2, CONCAT( Score3, '%') as Sem3 from table"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function in mysql

```
Select Name as Name, CONCAT(Score1,'%') as Sem1, CONCAT(Score2,'%') as Sem2, CONCAT(Score3,'%') as Sem3 from table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    Name AS Name,
    CONCAT(Score1, '%') AS Sem1,
    CONCAT(Score2, '%') AS Sem2,
    CONCAT(Score3, '%') AS Sem3
FROM table
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [CONCAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) feature in SQL.

```
Select Name as Name, CONCAT(Score1, '%') as Sem1, CONCAT(Score2 as Sem2, '%'), CONCAT(Score3 as Sem3, '%') from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a suffix to the results of a sql-query like this:

```
SELECT Name AS Name, Score1 & " %" AS Sem1, Score2 & " %" AS Sem2, Score3 & " %" AS Sem3 FROM table
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Use [CONCAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx)

```
Select Name as Name, CONCAT(Score1,'%') as Sem1, CONCAT(Score2,'%') as Sem2, CONCAT(Score3,'%') as Sem3 from table
```